# Tracking web page via osm(open street map)

Tags: javascript, html, openstreetmap, tracking, openlayers-3

I need to create a web page which will track a person via the open street map in which lat-long data will be sent via an app installed on his phone. the app will send the lat and long in JSON file to a server in a database from where my web page will take the data and show the path followed by the biker in dotted lines throughout the journey. I also searched for open layers simple examples... but couldn't get any more info... if anyone has done that please tell me how to approach in this and how to do it. Thank you guys

I have to show the path followed by the person and in my map, with all the values of lat and long present in the database... I have to show a dotted line which is followed by the person.... I have integrated the map by passing the current lat and long in static data format.... but facing problem for dynamic fetching ... how can i show dotted line i.e the path which is followed by him...

this is my code-- js code-

```
<script>
  function init() 
  {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
    var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    map.addLayer(mapnik);

    var lonlat1 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(77.64760799999999,12.9081357).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") // to Spherical Mercator
      );
    var lonlat2 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(78.64760799999999,11.9081357).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913") // to Spherical Mercator
      );  

    var zoom = 8;

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat1));
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat2));
    map.setCenter(lonlat2, zoom);
    map.setCenter(lonlat1, zoom);

  }
</script>
<body onload="init();">
<p><h3 id="h3">Tracking Page With An Embeded Map</h3></p>
<div id="mapdiv"></div>
```

just help me to dynamically fetch multiple data from the database and how to show that on the map. Above is the code for static long lat values only.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openlayers_Track_example

Anyway the example takes the data from a .gpx file. Here you could keep saving your coordinates in local storage:

```
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
        projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326'),
        tracking: true
      });
geolocation.once('change:position', function() {
        console.log(geolocation.getPosition());
       $rootScope.map.getView().setCenter(geolocation.getPosition())
      });
```

With this you get the coordinates, and you save them in localstorage through:

```
localStorage.setItem(someIndex,theLocationYouGot);
```

(Remember that you can't store objects in localstorage, so you will need to JSON.stringify it!)
To get the items from localstorage, you can use the following:

```
var objeto = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(someIndex));
```

And then you add the feature to your layer!

Greetings!

Comment: thanks for the help... i have used a code to extract my values of lon-lat from a text file but the thing is i have to extract it directly from database and store it in a file from where i will have to pass them....if you dont mind can you pass the code in my mail .... rohitrkbe@gmail.com... thanks dude....

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest you using local storage in the real time app, and save them (if you need) in the database at some certain event (for example every 10 minutes), just for having the data stored. Sadly I don't have the code, but what I wrote earlier might help you. By the way, I can see that your are using openlayers2, not openlayers3, please have this in mind and edit your post tags in order to get better help!

Answer (score 0):

this is the code that i am doing...

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
var position = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text( "My Points",
                { location:"./textfile.txt",
                  projection: map.displayProjection
                });
map.addLayer(position);
var layer_switcher= new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({});
map.addControl(layer_switcher);
//Set start centrepoint and zoom    
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( 9.5788, 48.9773 )
      .transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject());
var zoom=12;
map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom);
```

the text file format is:

```
lat lon icon    iconSize    iconOffset
```

48.9459301  9.6075669   icon_purple.png 35,35   0,-24
48.9899851  9.5382032   icon.png    35,35   -8,-8

problem is when i am inserting more data into the file it is not reading it... and have to code for reading it directly from database.